# How to configure maven install to skip tests in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Is it possible to configure run as maven install in eclipse to skip unit tests? If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

1. Ensure Maven is configured for your project
2. Right-click on your project
3. Go to 'Run As'
4. Select 'Run Configurations'
5. In the left-hand column, right-click 'Maven Build' and select 'New'
6. Select the base directory (the project) you want to build from
7. Write 'install' and any other goals you want in the 'Goals' field
8. Click the 'Skip Tests' radio button
9. Click Run!

Comment: this worked very fine but any ideas how to add this new configuration to the Run As menu instead of running it from run configuration ?

Comment: I'm glad it worked - If that's possible I'm not aware how. I have to go into the Run Configuration dialog every time I want to run a custom run configuration.

Comment: Not usre this is correct. Eclipse performs a -Dmaven.test.skip=true if you check this option which is different than -DskipTests on that the latest compiles the tests but does not run them.

Comment: Can you please tell me, whether it is possible to do the same for something like default setting of maven plugin for all maven projects or we can only skip tests for individual project always?

Answer (score 7):

accordig to [maven's document](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html) you can write this in you pom.xml:

```
<project>


[...]
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <configuration>
      <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: This applies to any Maven build (including command-line, which a CI server would use). I believe the OP wanted instructions specific to running in eclipse without affecting command-line usage.

Comment: With this plugin, you can **uncheck the "Skip Tests" box in Eclipse** (which adds -Dmaven.test.skip=true). This plugin is like adding -DskipTests, which as noted in @janagn's comment, compiles the tests but does not run them.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on maven test plugin that you use. You can try add parameter `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` to your build configuration.

Answer (score 5):

You can put the property maven.test.skip in a profile in your pom. And then you activate this profile in eclipse in the project properties of maven in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

At the Run configurations there is a Maven Build type of Run configuration. At that you could set up the standard Maven skipTests parameter.

Comment: can you please add steps for doing that, coz i can't figure it out ?

Comment: Open the Run menu, select Run configurations..., and there look on the left side for your existing maven configuration. Then on the right side you have a table for parameters, and add the maven.test.skip parameter with the value true.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in my Pom.xml turned off the tests for me - but at maven build, not at maven install.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
               <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Got to your root project and right click [image: screenshot of the menu that opens at right click]
- Got to run as and click on run configurations
- On the left, go to Maven Build, right click and create new
- Choose your base project, give a name in the goals textfield, add
  your kind of build and add the parameters -DskipTests=true
  -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true[image: screenshot of the build parameters window]

**An example of a maven build goal to skip tests is: clean install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true.**