# Maven Build successful but my test case didnt run in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created a simple Maven project in Eclipse to add and subtract 2 numbers -

wen i Run as Maven build - build successful but my test case didnt run.

Below is the console output:
[image: console output]

below is my Pom.xml:

[image: pom.xml]

Can any please help ...

Thanks

Comment: You should paste your `pom.xml` as code here.

Comment: Where are you tests located? And how are they named?

Comment: test is located in src/test/java

Comment: named as com.jai.training.jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you didn't click on 'Skip Tests' radio button, then check your test location.

Comment: wer will i find skip test radio button

Comment: Here is a link to SOF for steps how to skip the tests:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923002/how-to-configure-maven-install-to-skip-tests-in-eclipse

Comment: Try reengineering, I unfortunately use IntelliJ soo I cant help more.