# Not able create to jar due to "kafka" host "No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers"

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Implementation:

Project2 with kafka consumer only.

Im trying to create jar for this application with host "kafka:9092" but create error "No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers" unless if i make it "localhost:9092 or 127.0.0.1:9092 etc".

Project1 with kafka producer.
This is working and able to create jar even the host is kafka:9092

Reason for creating jar is for Docker-compose

```
//application.properties

spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092
```

```
//Error

2022-05-08 22:50:47.798  WARN 1824 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils     : Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka
2022-05-08 22:50:47.798  INFO 1824 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics scheduler closed
2022-05-08 22:50:47.798  INFO 1824 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2022-05-08 22:50:47.799  INFO 1824 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics reporters closed
2022-05-08 22:50:47.802  INFO 1824 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.consumer for consumer-productkafka-consumer-1 unregistered
2022-05-08 22:50:47.803  WARN 1824 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
2022-05-08 22:50:47.820  INFO 1824 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-05-08 22:50:47.837 ERROR 1824 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136) ~[spring-boot-test-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248) ~[spring-test-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:823) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:664) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:416) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:384) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:360) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:327) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:304) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:758) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:344) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:430) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:209) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:430) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:331) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:276) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.2.jar:2.8.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:88) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:47) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:730) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.0.jar:na]
```

Comment: This is because of your junit suite, which is running during packaging and looking for "kafka:9092" change this  to localhost:9092 or update junit test case.

Comment: This error isn't preventing you from creating a JAR. It's just failing the tests... You can skip the tests to create a JAR. Also, is your producer code actually _flushing it's buffer_? Otherwise, it won't actually write the data to try to connect to that address

Comment: Thank you again sir, here is my reference to skip the test to create jar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923002/how-to-configure-maven-install-to-skip-tests-in-eclipse its working now

Comment: You should definitely fix the tests, though. I'm just saying that's not what is preventing the jar from being built

Comment: Noted, actually it has docker-compose that has user define network which connected to other docker compose with kafka and that project has producer with contianer of kafka only while this project has consumer has to listen only with "no" configuration of kafka container  both of this project are separated. After i skip the test, it can now listen and capture kafka:9092